# confused about using instances of Ember objects and whether items should be declared as properties or what that even means

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to get my feet wet in using Ember by using Ember Objects for my models and am using this part of the guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_initializing-instances . I have a class named InventoryItem and am not using EmberData nor EmberObject.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.InventoryItem = Ember.Object.extend({
    init:function(){
      var idTEST=this.get('id');  // <- id in class but idTEST so that clear
      var binNumber=this.get('bin_number');
    },
    say:function(){
      alert('here is my binNumber:' + binNumber); // <- undefined
      alert('here is my binNumber:' + this.binNumber); // <- undefined
      alert('here is my binNumber:' + this.get('bin_number')); // <- this works
    }
 
});

var ii=App.InventoryItem.create({ id:12, bin_number:'abc123'})
```

What would idTEST represent and binNumber represent? Are there properties in Ember?  When I use them later, I can't use  ii.idTEST or ii.binNumber and use ii.get('id') and ii.get('bin_number'). What would be the point of setting these 'properties' up (if that's what they are)?

Later in my app, I am using an instance of an Ember class intrpolated with javascript - should I be using like ii.get('bin_number')?

thx

### edit 1

do I need to do null checks for every item? can I mixin something to set to ''?

I tried

```
App.InventoryItem = Ember.Object.extend({
    inventory_notes:'',  // <- i thought that this would set it to empty string as a default if null but doesn't seem to work that way

  ....

  if(this.get('inventory_notes')===null){
    alert('you are null');
    this.set('inventory_notes','');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`idTEST` and `binNumber` variables are defined in the `init` function and they will be visible within the function scope only. In the `say` function those variables will not be defined instead, so that if you call `ii.say()` you will cause an exception. This plain Javascript.

What you want to do is using the object properties you are passing to the `create` function and using `get` and `set` functions to read and modify the value of such properties:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.InventoryItem = Ember.Object.extend({
   init: function() {
       // here you can do some initializations, e.g.
       this.set('test', this.get('id') + 1);
   },

   say:function(){
      alert('here is my binNumber:' + this.get('id'));
      alert('here is my binNumber:' + this.get('test')); // this will be 13
      alert('here is my binNumber:' + this.get('bin_number'));
   }
});

var ii=App.InventoryItem.create({ id:12, bin_number:'abc123'})
```

You can read more at [Ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx, that makes sense - so the hash passed in creates the highest level of properties by default? Since we're outputting the properties in a template, is there a pattern for handling null values. I'm currently doing something like edit #1 but it seems like this functionality should be built in.

Comment: You can use the `create` method to initialize properties, or you could also do something like `ii.set('bin_number', 'new-value')` to update properties once you have the object. About null values, it probably doesn't really matter. I would personally try to use `null` initially instead of empty strings. In templates you can use `{{#if obj.inventory_notes}}there is something{{/if}}` (see [template conditionals](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/conditionals/)).